Error calling sync triggers (BadRequest) -- Deploying Python Function App
I am trying to deploy an Azure Function App, but whenever I try to do so, I keep getting an error when it tries to sync triggers

If I deploy through the Azure Functions extension in VS Code, it works, but when I go to the Activity Logs tab in the Function App, the Sync Triggers fail.

I'm using Python 3.11 Linux Consumption Function App
I'm not using any external packages besides azure functions.
The connected storage account is open to all IP addresses (not what I want in the end, but I also tried limiting it to the IPs).
import azure.functions as func
import logging
from base64 import b64encode
import csv
import json
import os
import requests
import sys
from datetime import datetime as dt

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)
api_token = os.getenv('RANDORI_API_KEY')

if not api_token:
    print('Missing RANDORI_API_KEY environment variable')
    sys.exit(1)

RANDORI_PLATFORM_URL = 'https://app.randori.io'
api_path = 'recon/api/v1'
headers = {'Authorization': api_token, 
           "Content-Type": "application/json"}

def get_json(endpoint):
    all_entities = []
    url = f'{RANDORI_PLATFORM_URL}/{api_path}/{endpoint}'
    limit = 2000
    offset = 0
    params = {
        'limit' : limit,
        'offset' : offset
        }
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
    response.raise_for_status()
    return response.json()

def parse_targets(result):
    total_records = result['total']
    json_data = []
    for record in result['data']:
        priorityScore = round(record['priority_score'], 1)
        hostname = record.get('detection_criteria', {}).get('http', {}).get('host', '')
        ip = record['detection_criteria']['ip']['address']
        vendor = record['vendor']
        version = record['version']
        targetService = f'{vendor}, {record["name"]}, {version}'
        temptationScore = record['target_temptation']
        lastSeen = record['last_seen']
        timeGenerated = dt.now().isoformat()
        temptation = "Critical" if temptationScore >= 40 else "High" if temptationScore >= 30 else "Medium" if temptationScore >= 15 else "Low"
        priority = "High" if priorityScore > 29.98 else "Medium" if priorityScore > 20 else "Low"

        data = {
            'Priority': priority,
            'Hostname': hostname,
            'IP': ip,
            'Vendor': vendor,
            'Version': version,
            'TargetService': targetService,
            'Temptation': temptation,
            'LastSeen': lastSeen,
            'TimeGenerated': timeGenerated
        }
        json_data.append(data)
    return json_data

#write to json file
def write_json(data, filename):
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
    print(f"JSON file written to {filename}")
@app.route(route="test")
def test(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    data = get_json('target')
    json_data = parse_targets(data)
    write_json(json_data, 'targets.json')
    return func.HttpResponse('here', status_code=200)```


hi please can you copy out the error and format into a code


Make sure you have added necessary modules in requirements.txt file before deployment.

azure-functions
requests

Then, add RANDORI_API_KEY in Function App -> Environment Variables -> App settings as shown below

I have removed sys.exit(1) line from code and final code looks like below-
import azure.functions as func
import logging
from base64 import b64encode
import json
import os
import requests
from datetime import datetime as dt

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

api_token = os.getenv('RANDORI_API_KEY')

if not api_token:
    print('Missing RANDORI_API_KEY environment variable')

RANDORI_PLATFORM_URL = 'https://app.randori.io'
api_path = 'recon/api/v1'
headers = {'Authorization': api_token, 
           "Content-Type": "application/json"}

def get_json(endpoint):
    all_entities = []
    url = f'{RANDORI_PLATFORM_URL}/{api_path}/{endpoint}'
    limit = 2000
    offset = 0
    params = {
        'limit' : limit,
        'offset' : offset
        }
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
    response.raise_for_status()
    return response.json()

def parse_targets(result):
    total_records = result['total']
    json_data = []
    for record in result['data']:
        priorityScore = round(record['priority_score'], 1)
        hostname = record.get('detection_criteria', {}).get('http', {}).get('host', '')
        ip = record['detection_criteria']['ip']['address']
        vendor = record['vendor']
        version = record['version']
        targetService = f'{vendor}, {record["name"]}, {version}'
        temptationScore = record['target_temptation']
        lastSeen = record['last_seen']
        timeGenerated = dt.now().isoformat()
        temptation = "Critical" if temptationScore >= 40 else "High" if temptationScore >= 30 else "Medium" if temptationScore >= 15 else "Low"
        priority = "High" if priorityScore > 29.98 else "Medium" if priorityScore > 20 else "Low"

        data = {
            'Priority': priority,
            'Hostname': hostname,
            'IP': ip,
            'Vendor': vendor,
            'Version': version,
            'TargetService': targetService,
            'Temptation': temptation,
            'LastSeen': lastSeen,
            'TimeGenerated': timeGenerated
        }
        json_data.append(data)
    return json_data

#write to json file
def write_json(data, filename):
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
    print(f"JSON file written to {filename}")

@app.route(route="test")
def test(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    data = get_json('target')
    json_data = parse_targets(data)
    write_json(json_data, 'targets.json')
    return func.HttpResponse('here', status_code=200)




Still getting the Failing to Sync Triggers (BadRequest) error.

@KrishanPatel Are you able execute this function locally without any errors? If you have followed my steps then you should be able to deploy it successfully. How are you deploying it using command or vs code extension option?

I was able to execute it locally with no issues. When I deploy it with the vs code extension, it would work but show the error in the Activity Logs, whereas the command would fail during deployment. I ended up contacting Microsoft Support, and created a new function app to deploy to, and it worked then. For some reason, my original function app was missing the WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE and WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING environment variables, and I could not add them back in

I had this same issue while troubleshooting another issue with deployment. In my case this happened because I stopped the app.
Turns out the triggers cannot be synced when the app is stopped.
